# WPF datagrid not refreshing like asked

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a weird situation in one of my program when a datagrid's content is not update when I call the grid.items.refresh command.

I do know that the source of the grid is updated as it should and should I quit the windows and reopen it, which has the effect of giving the itemssource back to the datagrid, the grid is now OK.

Are there any known bug with the items.refresh command of the datagrid or is there something I am not doing right ?

Thanks,

Edit : Forgot to mention, this only seems to happen on my client computer. As usual, it's working here, but I did see the problem myself. I just can't explain it.

Comment: What are you using as the grid's source?

Comment: It's a List (Of Something), typically, when the content is changed, a function is called to perform some calculation and refresh the grid's content, and some other when needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

On your DataGrid column definitions, you can add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your Column Bindings.

> ie: Binding="{Binding Path=Product.ProductCode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

If that does not help, consider changing your List to an [`ObservableCollection<OfSomething>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx). Then WPF's data binding will automatically react to changes within your source.

Comment: Does the observablecollection have already all the mecanism for this and can I use it the same I would use a List ?

Comment: +1 You should use a class that implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) when performing data binding in WPF. `ObservableCollection` is often a common base class to start from.